SSRS data label positioning on a range bar chart
I have created a waterfall-esque chart in SSRS using a range bar chart and it looks like the following:
SSRS Waterfall Chart
I'm trying to get the data label positions to be top if value is positive and below if value is negative.
I have linked the original article that I used to create this waterfall chart, if you scroll to the bottom you see that his chart has the labels in this position so it must be possible. Waterfall Chart in SSRS
Any ideas how I can get the data labels to move in this format?
I used this expression in the Chart Series Labels Properties > Appearance > Position: (=iif(Fields!Value.Value >= 0,"Top","Bottom")) but this made didn't change the position at all. Even simply setting the position to Top didn't move the labels.
